# In Delphi, how can I modify cells in a TStringGrid using a DLL procedure?

Tags: class, delphi, pointers, dll, tstringgrid

In Embarcadero Delphi v10.1 I have both a DLL library with a record, and a VCL application containing a TStringGrid and a TEdit. The idea is to take the shortstring entered into the TEdit; save it to the record in the DLL and then use the data stored in the record to fill in one of the cells in the TStringGrid.

My problem is that after saving the shortstring to the record I can't seem to find a way to access the TStringGrid while inside the DLL procedure. So far I have tried using both classes and pointers to access the TStringGrid in the DLL but neither has worked:

```
type
  pstringgrid = ^TStringGrid;

//or

type
  pstringgrid = ^stringgrid1;

//or

type
  istringgrid = class(TStringGrid);
```

I have even tried to import the TStringGrid into the procedure which is supposed to enter the shortstring from the record into the TStringGrid:

```
procedure AddElement (var grid : stringgrid1); stdcall; 

//or

type
  pstringgrid = ^TStringGrid;

procedure AddElement (var grid : ^pstringgrid); stdcall;
```

So far nothing has worked and all I am getting is the "undecleared identifier" error message from the debugger; please help! How can I access and edit a TStringGrid while in a DLL procedure?

Edit:

Here is the relevant code, sorry for the foreign variable names.

The DLL:

```
library BibliotekaDLL;

uses
  System.SysUtils,
  System.Classes;

type
  StringGrid1 = class(TStringGrid);
  plist = ^game;
  game = record
    nazwa: shortstring;
    wydawca: shortstring;
    rokwyd: integer;
    gatunek1: shortstring;
    gatunek2: shortstring;
    pointer: plist;
  end;

var
  BazaDanych : file of game;
  first, current: plist;

[...]

procedure WyswietlListe; stdcall;
var
  row : integer;
begin
  AssignFile(BazaDanych, 'c:\Baza_Danych_Gier.dat');
  if not FileExists('c:\Baza_Danych_Gier.dat') then
    ShowMessage ('Baza Danych Nie Instnieje' +E.Message)
  else
    begin
    Reset(BazaDanych);
    Read(BazaDanych, first);
    Close(BazaDanych);
    current := first;
    row := 1;
    while current^.pointer <> nil do
      begin
      current := first;
      StringGrid1.Cells[0,row] := current^.nazwa;
      StringGrid1.Cells[1,row] := current^.wydawca;
      StringGrid1.Cells[2,row] := current^.rokwyd;
      StringGrid1.Cells[3,row] := current^.gatunek1;
      StringGrid1.Cells[4,row] := current^.gatunek2;
      current := current^.pointer;
      row = row +1;
      StringGrid1.RowCount := row;
      end;
    if current^.pointer = nil do
      begin
        StringGrid1.Cells[0,row] := current^.nazwa;
        StringGrid1.Cells[1,row] := current^.wydawca;
        StringGrid1.Cells[2,row] := current^.rokwyd;
        StringGrid1.Cells[3,row] := current^.gatunek1;
        StringGrid1.Cells[4,row] := current^.gatunek2;
      end;
    end;
end;

[...]
```

And the VCL application code:

```
[...]

type
  TForm1 = class(TForm)
    Button2: TButton;
    StringGrid1: TStringGrid;
    procedure Button2Click(Sender: TObject);
  end;

var
  Form1: TForm1;

implementation

[...]

procedure TForm1.Button2Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  Handle : THandle;
  WyswietlListe : procedure;
begin
  Handle := LoadLibrary('BibliotekaDLL.dll');
  try
    @WyswietlListe:= GetProcAddress(Handle, 'WyswietlListe');
    if @WyswietlListe = nil then raise Exception.Create('Nie Można Znaleźć Procedury w Bibliotece!');
    WyswietlListe;
  finally
    FreeLibrary(Handle);
  end;
end;

[...]
```

Comment: Don't understand your use of pointers. Classes are already pointers. Too much indirection. Passing any of those types across module boundaries doesn't work, unless you use packages. It's 2017. Stop using shortstring. Show us a [mcve] so we can understand the interop.

Comment: I feel for you, but there are just so many problems here it is almost impossible to know where to begin. I just haven't got the energy for this

Answer (score 1):

> My problem is that after saving the shortstring to the record I can't seem to find a way to access the TStringGrid while inside the DLL procedure.

Don't do that.  It is bad design.

For one thing, it is not safe to access objects across the DLL boundary unless both app and DLL are compiled with Runtime Packages enabled so they share a single instance of the RTL and memory manager.

It is best if the DLL has no knowledge of your UI at all.  If the DLL needs to communicate info to the app, the DLL should define a callback event that the app can assign a handler for, and then the DLL can call that event when needed.  Let the app decide how to manage its own UI.

Also, your `game` record has a pointer member, but pointers cannot be persisted in files.  You need to remove that member.

Try something more like this:

```
library BibliotekaDLL;

uses
  System.SysUtils,
  System.Classes,
  Vcl.Dialogs;

type
  game = packed record
    nazwa: shortstring;
    wydawca: shortstring;
    rokwyd: integer;
    gatunek1: shortstring;
    gatunek2: shortstring;
  end;

  gameCallback = procedure(var g: game; userData: Pointer); stdcall;

procedure WyswietlListe(callback: gameCallback; userData: Pointer); stdcall;
var
  BazaDanych : File of game;
  current: game;
begin
  AssignFile(BazaDanych, 'c:\Baza_Danych_Gier.dat');
  Reset(BazaDanych);
  if IOResult <> 0 then
    ShowMessage ('Baza Danych Nie Instnieje')
  else
  try
    repeat
      Read(BazaDanych, current);
      if IOResult <> 0 then Break;
      if Assigned(callback) then callback(current, userData);
    until False;
  finally
    Close(BazaDanych);
  end;
end;

exports
  WyswietlListe;

end.
```

```
interface

type
  TForm1 = class(TForm)
    Button2: TButton;
    StringGrid1: TStringGrid;
    procedure Button2Click(Sender: TObject);
  end;

var
  Form1: TForm1;

implementation

type
  game = packed record
    nazwa: shortstring;
    wydawca: shortstring;
    rokwyd: integer;
    gatunek1: shortstring;
    gatunek2: shortstring;
  end;

  gameCallback = procedure(var g: game; userData: Pointer); stdcall;

  pmyCallbackInfo = ^myCallbackInfo;
  myCallbackInfo = record
    Grid: TStringGrid;
    FirstTime: Boolean;
  end;

procedure myCallback(var g: game; userData: Pointer); stdcall;
var
  row: Integer;
begin
  Grid := pmyCallbackInfo(userData).Grid;

  // add a new row only if the initial non-fixed row is already filled...
  if pmyCallbackInfo(userData).FirstTime then
    pmyCallbackInfo(userData).FirstTime := False
  else
    Grid.RowCount := Grid.RowCount + 1;

  row := Grid.RowCount - 1;
  Grid.Cells[0, row] := g.nazwa;
  Grid.Cells[1, row] := g.wydawca;
  Grid.Cells[2, row] := IntToStr(g.rokwyd);
  Grid.Cells[3, row] := g.gatunek1;
  Grid.Cells[4, row] := g.gatunek2;
end;

procedure TForm1.Button2Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  DLLHandle : THandle;
  WyswietlListe : procedure(callback: gameCallback; userData: Pointer); stdcall;
  info: myCallbackInfo;
begin
  // clear the TStringGrid. However, it has an odd quirk
  // that it requires at least 1 non-fixed row at all times...
  //
  StringGrid1.RowCount := StringGrid1.FixedRows + 1;
  StringGrid1.Rows[StringGrid1.RowCount - 1].Clear;

  DLLHandle := LoadLibrary('BibliotekaDLL.dll');
  if DLLHandle = 0 then raise Exception.Create(...);
  try
    @WyswietlListe := GetProcAddress(DLLHandle, 'WyswietlListe');
    if not Assigned(WyswietlListe) then raise Exception.Create('Nie Można Znaleźć Procedury w Bibliotece!');
    info.Grid := StringGrid1;
    info.FirstTime := True;
    WyswietlListe(@myCallback, @info);
  finally
    FreeLibrary(DLLHandle);
  end;
end;
```